# How can I sort by multiple fields in LINQ?

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

how can I do multiple sort in

```
 return (from p in _db.Pages where p.int_PostStatusId == 2 select p).OrderByDescending(m => m.int_SortOrder);
```

i want to do order by by int_PageId as well? first by int_SortOrder then by int_PageId

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use either [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112.aspx) or [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534958.aspx) to order the result of an `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`:

```
return (...)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.int_SortOrder)
    .ThenBy(m => m.int_PageId);
```

Or using the query syntax:

```
orderby p.int_SortOrder descending, p.int_PageId
```